Confusing About Google Recaptcha Server Address
I am implementing Google reCAPTCHA for my application, and I came across two different API endpoints for verifying reCAPTCHA tokens:
The official Google reCAPTCHA documentation specifies the verification API endpoint as:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
However, in the GCP reCAPTCHA Enterprise service documentation, the endpoint for verification is mentioned as:
https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/\<project-name>/assessments?key=API_KEY
It seems both serve a similar purpose: verifying reCAPTCHA tokens.
Why are there two different endpoints for what appears to be the same functionality? Is the difference related to the Enterprise version of reCAPTCHA?
Should I always use the Enterprise endpoint if my project is configured in GCP?
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
I reviewed both the official reCAPTCHA documentation and the GCP console reCAPTCHA integration detail documentation. I expected both to refer to the same API endpoint for token verification, but they list two different endpoints. I am unsure which one to use and why the difference exists.

Google "does this" (has evolved historically?) to offer different endpoints for seemingly (!?) the same service and this can be confusing. I'm unfamiliar with the reCAPTCHA service but I think the difference here is between the non- and enterprise versions. Generally (!) the GCP or enterprise services are on (or are migrated to) googleapis.com domain and are documented by APIs Explorer viz e.g. reCAPTCHA Enterprise API.

Google's Cloud (!) Client Libraries mostly (there are probably exceptions) use googleapis.com endpoints and other|earlier APIs are JavaScript-oriented (e.g. Maps).

The reason is historical, but the tl;dr is that you should use the latter.
reCAPTCHA Classic
The siteverify endpoint is referred to as "reCAPTCHA Classic". Previously the workflow was:

Create and manage your reCAPTCHA key in the reCAPTCHA Admin console
Send tokens to the https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify endpoint for assessment

This approach is essentially deprecated. In the Admin console you can still manage existing keys, but you cannot create new ones. Google is encouraging calls to the siteverify endpoint to move to the GCP service endpoint. See the migration docs https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha/docs/migrate-recaptcha
reCAPTCHA Enterprise
A few years back reCAPTCHA was integrated as a GCP product, hence the new endpoint https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/
The current workflow is:

Create and manage reCAPTCHA site keys using:

GCP Cloud Console https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha/ (docs)
gcloud sdk (docs)
REST API (docs)


Send tokens to the reCAPTCHA GCP API for assessment

REST endpoint (docs)
Client libraries (docs)



